# how to select Multiple activities in android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, arraylist

How to select multipleActivities?
I have a **listview** it consists of multiple activity .if i select multiple list i want to **startactivity** of selected list   .

Comment: you mean that each row in your listview takes you to a different activity from the other?

Comment: You're asking SO to do something so basic, you should really be able to do it by yourself. Please google around until you do it, instead of asking here at the very minimal problem.

Comment: @SamiKanafani : yes but i want to startactivity of multiple selection of list

Comment: i am doing survey application ..i have seven activities i represnted that in listview .if i select more than one list i have to startactivity of selected list one after the other

Comment: Please provide a image or clearer explanation as your terminology seems to be of

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
    switch(position){
    case 0:
    //Open first activity 
    startActivity(new Intent(context,Activity1.class));
    break;
    case 1:
    //Open second activity 
    startActivity(new Intent(context,Activity2.class));
    break;
    //So on...!!

    }
}
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am using 8 activities in list view if i select more than one list application should open first selected list and then i have continue button inside activity if i click on continue button application should open second selected list.